# Delete/Edit record in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejsbootrap's .
I want to edit or delete single record at a time.

```
<b-table :items="products" :fields="fields">
  <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
    <a @click='editRecord()'><font-awesome-icon icon="edit" /></a> | 
    <a @click='deleteRecord()'><font-awesome-icon icon="trash-alt" 
    /></a>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

i am calling editRecord and deleteRecord but i am unable to pass current record object or id to method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `row` variable from the slot scope:

```
<template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
  <a @click='editRecord(row)'><font-awesome-icon icon="edit" /></a> | 
  <a @click='deleteRecord(row)'><font-awesome-icon icon="trash-alt"/></a>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank U very much. Now i am understanding vuejs little bit.